# Fractional display scaling: get and set in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, scaling

How do I get current fractional scaling value via terminal?

E.g. with GUI set to 125%:
[image]

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor` returns 0

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor` returns 1.0

Can't see anything relevant in the list of other `org.gnome.desktop.interface` variables.